# ffmpeg side by side camera and audio recording

Tags: linux, audio-recording, alsa, video-recording

I want to record 2 webcams side by side and also microphone simultaneously.

I succeed to record 2 webcam side by side command below.

ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video3 -s pal -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 -s pal -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[v];[v][1:v:0]overlay=w" -s 1280x576 -r 30 12345.mp4 -threads 8

but i can not find any way to add "-f alsa -i default" to my command.

Is there any one who can know how to?

Also i want v4l2loop to use same device. I want to use /dev/video* for recording and also playing at the same time. I can not find any solution for kernel 2.6.32

Comment: have you tried chaining the commands with `&` for background operation?

Comment: in my code i want to record 2 webcams and microphone in a same clip. So i think background operation will not solve the issue.
I think I have problem while adding the audio in -filter_complex parameter.